# Downloading images from Parse.com and using them for iCarousel

Tags: ios, parse-platform, icarousel

please help me!

I download images from Parse.com like this:

```
self.images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
PFImageView *creature = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SubCatergory"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError *error) {

    for (PFObject *comment in comments) {

        PFFile *file = [comment objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
        creature.file = file;
        creature.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
        // creature.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
        [creature loadInBackground];

        //[self.images addObject:creature];

           [self.images addObject: creature];

    }


}];
```

put these in iCarousel:

```
-(UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{    

        PFImageView* img = [self.images objectAtIndex:index];
        PFImageView* imgView = [[PFImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
        return img;

}
```

With local images works iCarousel fine. I set the delegates and datasource.
The content of my images array is like this:

>",
    "

I got the error:

> [PFImageView length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xf40e9d0

Comment: The content of my images array is like this:

<PFImageView: 0xf40e9d0; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (0 0; 100 100); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xf40ea90>>",
    "<PFImageView: 0xf40e9d0; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (0 0; 100 100); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xf40ea90>>",

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question and I think you have already found the issue with your code. In short, if you look carefully:

```
PFImageView* img = [self.images objectAtIndex:index];
PFImageView* imgView = [[PFImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
```

you are using `img`, which is actually a `UIImageView` derived class in place of a `UIImage` when you call `initWithImage`.

This explains your crash. You can safely return `[self.images objectAtIndex:index]` from your `carousel:viewForItemAtIndex:` method:

```
-(UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view {

  return [self.images objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you alot,

```
self.images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"SubCatergory"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError *error) {

    for (PFObject *comment in comments) {
      PFFile *post = [comment objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
      [self.images addObject:post]; } 
    }];


-(UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view {
          AsyncImageView *imageasy=[[AsyncImageView alloc] init];   
               [imageasy setImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[post url]]];
  return imageasy.image;
}
```